# Auto Desk Infrastructure Map Studio 2013 Invoke Url

Tags: asp.net, gis, layer, autodesk, mapguide

Hi All I am making a map on Auto Desk Infrastructure Map Guide Studio. Now I created a small ASP.NET website and hosted in local machine, Now on click of different buttons in flexible layout toolbar, I invoke URL that asp.net page and it opens fine. I do some data querying on that page by selecting different options and execute query. The data changes in table in database and the effect is shown on the layer on map. Ok the issue is that I want to refresh the Auto desk map after invoke URL window is closed. And I want to do it by configuration in Map studio 2013. Does anyone have any idea how to refresh map automatically after **invoke URL? Or in other sense if the data in the data source of layer is changed.**

**Addtional Info:** the map always refresh when I click the refresh button from top or if I drag it or zoom it..Otherwise new layer data stays same. HELP !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the map or a layer after calling an asp.net page, you must include a call to the Refresh method of the Viewer API linked OnClose event of your asp.net page.